# Generation and detection of tones

Tags: java, android, audio, dtmf

I am looking for a successful method to identify self-generated sounds.

My idea is to spend even two different sounds over stereo. The two tones differ in their frequency. The tones I turn then back on a self-made cables for the microphone. The cable has two switches, which switches between the left or the right channel.

I want to note which of the two frequencies arrived at the microphone input, and then count them.

I've tried many things, but nothing brought the desired success. Well, I came across DTMF, but the implementation in Android is insufficient.

Does anyone have any idea what I can try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of the input audio. What you would need to do is capture a short window of audio, run an FFT, and then analyze the result. FFTs are a bit a complicated if you're not familiar with them, but it's possible to count and measure tones, provided that they're sufficiently separated in frequency.

Comment: I agree.  The FFT is the most important algorithm in signal processing.  If your question is "How can I analyze the frequencies in a signal", the answer probably starts with "Calculate an FFT."  There might be some special optimizations if you know exactly which frequencies to look for, but the FFT is the most general and powerful tool.

Comment: How long will it take to record the right frequency with the FFT? The switch is closed for only less then 10ms.

Comment: The window size (e.g. 10ms) will determine how far apart the tones will have to be in frequency to be detected.  If you record 10ms of audio at a 44.1KHz sampling rate, you won't have much data.  Make sure the tones are separated by _at least_ 500 Hz in frequency to ensure you have a reasonable chance of seeing distinct peaks in the FFT output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FSK modulation and demodulation.  You don't need an FFT, as this can be done more simply by narrow-band DSP filters (a couple of Goertzel filters), or quadrature demodulators.